# .Net Reactor and ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, obfuscation

I'm trying to obfuscate An ASP.NET Core APP, I found that .NET Reactor tool- I tried it on my APP DLL Assembly which exist in Bin Release but when i try to run it from visual studio I got PlatformNotSupported Exception. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that would be useful for anyone I used [Dotfuscator](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/compare-editions) on both Dlls in obj\release\netcoreapp2.0 the one named after your app name and the other has the app name post-fixed with .PrecompiledViews then I copied (and replaced non obfuscated ones)them on my published (on server) app and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Please update to the latest .NET Reactor version as it should correctly detect/protect ASP.NET Core assemblies.